# Reload page after file download via Response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, refresh, response

I'm writing a reporting tool in which you can display a report straight to the page or download it as an excel file. In case you just want to show it on the page the site reloads as expected. in case it is downloaded as excel file the download works but the page is not reloaded. Thats a problem for me because I have no clue how to disable the loading animation afterwards. The download is accomplished with a write action to the response object. Here is the code:

```
private void ExcelExport(DataTable outList)
{
     ViewBag.Reload = true;
     Response.ClearContent();
     Response.Buffer = true;
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xls");
     Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
     Response.Charset = "";
     Response.Output.Write(Excel.GetXml(outList));
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
}
```

The code is called from an ActionResult method within my controller (where the ExcelExport Method is also located):

```
public ActionResult WisPriceMatrix(string cc, string sl, string exp)
{
     ViewBag.StorageLocations = this.StorageLocations;
     ViewBag.WisPriceMatrixReport = null;
     int cleanCode = 3;
     if ((cc != null && cc != string.Empty && Int32.TryParse(cc, out cleanCode)) || (sl != null && sl != string.Empty))
     {
          sl = sl == string.Empty ? null : sl;

          ViewBag.ParameterSl = sl;
          ViewBag.ParameterCleanCode = cleanCode;

          DataTable outList = dc.GetWisPriceMatrix(sl, cleanCode);

          if (exp == null || exp == string.Empty || exp != "1")
          {
               ViewBag.WisPriceMatrixReport = outList;
          }
          else
          {
                if (outList.Count > 0)
                {
                     this.ExcelExport(outList);
                }
                else
                {
                     ViewBag.NoResults = "1";
                }
           }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Any Ideas how I could force the page to reload afterwards?

I tried to create a ViewBag variable that would indicate that a reload is neede and react to it via JavaScript but since the page isn't refreshed this is of nu success ;-).

Comment: post more code here who you are calling ExcelExport method...????

Comment: I have edited my question with the corresponding code.

Comment: don't able to understand what exactly you want???

Comment: After I call this ExcelExport Method, the View is not reloaded. In stead it just stays in the state before the response was sent. But I need it to reload.

Comment: above shown is your post method???

Comment: i think below answer will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

In your case in order to reload page either you can use `Viewbag` and set `Viewbag` value on Controller say `Viewbag.data="reload"` and then on view check `Viewbag` as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if('@Viewbag.data' == "reload")
  {
    window.location.reload(true);
  }
});
```

OR you can just instead of  `return View()` use `return RedirectToAction("WisPriceMatrix")` as `RedirectToAction` create a new `http(302)` request and reloads the page.

Comment: I allready tried somethig similar to the first suggestion. But this doesn't work since the site isnt reloaded and thus the script isn't executed again. I just tried the second suggestion which doesn't work either. The command `return RedirectToAction("WisPriceMatrix");` is reached but has no impact on the result.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé...second answer will sure shot work...just check your httpget and httppost controller actions have name "WisPriceMatrix"..??

Comment: The controller Action is named "WisPriceMatrix" but I think after editing the response manually the behavior of the `RedirectToAction`Method is not as expected.

Comment: Ok, then it is not working because of another reason.

Comment: No. As I said, after editing the response the return of any action has no result.